# Derivative of a curve on a manifold in time-dependent (rotating, comoving) coordinates

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, rotational-dynamics, coordinate-systems

This should maybe go in the math SE but the example is more relevant to physics and the way physicists think so I'm posting here.

**what I understand:** Let $\mathcal{Q}$ be a smooth $n$-dim manifold and $q=(q^1,\dots, q^n):Q\to\mathbb{R}^n$ some local coordinates. Then the derivative of a curve, $r:t\mapsto r_t\in\mathcal{Q}$, is expressed in the local $q^i$ coordinate basis, $\boldsymbol{\partial}_i$ with dual 1-forms $\pmb{d}q^i$, as

$$
  \pmb{v}_t = \tfrac{d}{dt} r_t = \tfrac{d}{dt}(q^i\circ r)_t \boldsymbol{\partial}_i|_{r_t} =: \dot{q}^i(t)\boldsymbol{\partial}_i|_{r_t} \; \in T_{r_t}\mathcal{Q}
\quad,\qquad   \dot{q}^i = \tfrac{d}{dt}(q^i\circ r) = \pmb{d}q^i\cdot\pmb{v} = v^i
$$

(I will omit the $|_{r_t}$ on $\boldsymbol{\partial}_i|_{r_t}$ from now on.) That is, the components of the velocity in the $q^i$-basis are equivalent to the derivatives of the coordinate functions along the curve: $v^i(t)=\dot{q}^i(t)$.

**what I don't understand:** what happens when the coordinates are also explicit functions of time? That is, local coordinates $\tilde{q}=(\tilde{q}^1,\dots,\tilde{q}^n):Q\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$. The velocity is a coordinate-agnostic vector so, if the above is correct, we should get

$$ \pmb{v}_t=\tfrac{d}{dt} r_t = \tfrac{d}{dt}(q^i\circ r)_t \boldsymbol{\partial}_i =  \tfrac{d}{dt}(\tilde{q}^i\circ r)_t \tilde{\boldsymbol{\partial}}_i \qquad\quad (*)
$$

but that does not seem to be the case as illustrated by the following simple example.

**Example:** Let $\mathcal{Q}=\mathbb{E}^3$ be classic flat 3-space, let $q=(q^1,\dots, q^n)$ be some linear coordinates in a fixed/inertial basis, $\pmb{e}_i\in\mathbb{E}^3$, and let  $\tilde{q}=(\tilde{q}^1,\dots,\tilde{q}^n)$ be linear coordinates in a rotating basis, $\tilde{\pmb{e}}_i(t)=\pmb{R}(t)\cdot\pmb{e}_i\in\mathbb{E}^3$. Since our manifold is a vector space, we have the privilege of regarding a point, $r\in\mathbb{E}^3$, as a displacement vector, $\pmb{r}=q^i\pmb{e}_i=\tilde{q}^i(t)\tilde{\pmb{e}}_i(t)$. It is well known the the velocity along some $r_t$ is expressed in the inertial and the rotating bases as:

$$
  \pmb{v}_t = \tfrac{d}{dt} r_t = \dot{q}^i(t)\boldsymbol{\partial}_i \;=\; ( \dot{\tilde{q}}^i(t) + \tilde{\Omega}^i_j(t) \tilde{q}^j(t)) \tilde{\boldsymbol{\partial}}_i(t) \,=\, \tilde{v}^i(t)\tilde{\boldsymbol{\partial}}_i(t)
\quad,\qquad 
 \tilde{v}^i:= \pmb{v}\cdot\pmb{d}\tilde{q}^i = \dot{\tilde{q}}^i + \tilde{\Omega}^i_j \tilde{q}^j = C^i_j v^j = C^i_j v^j 
$$

where I've identified  $\boldsymbol{\partial}_i\cong \pmb{e}_i$ and $\tilde{\boldsymbol{\partial}}_i\cong \tilde{\pmb{e}}_i$ (again, since $\mathcal{Q}=\mathbb{E}^3$ is a vector space) and
where $\tilde{\Omega}^i_j(t)$ are the components of the rotating basis's angular velocity tensor (in the rotating basis). That is, $\tilde{\Omega}^i_j=C^i_k\dot{R}^k_j$ where $\tilde{\pmb{e}}_i(t) = R^j_i(t) \pmb{e}_j$ and $C^i_k R^k_j=\delta^i_j$ such that $\tilde{q}^i = C^i_j q^j$ and $q^i=R^i_j \tilde{q}^j$ and $\dot{R}=R\tilde{\Omega}$ and $\dot{C}=-\tilde{\Omega}C$. Note $v^i=\dot{q}^i$ but $\tilde{v}^i \neq \dot{\tilde{q}}^i$.

Now,  $\tilde{q}^i(t):=\tilde{q}^i\circ r_t$ is expressed in terms of $\tilde{q}^i$ and $q^i$ as
$\tilde{q}^i\circ r_t= \tilde{q}^i(t) = C^i_j(t) q^j(t)$ then

$$
  \tfrac{d}{dt}(\tilde{q}^i\circ {r}) = \tfrac{d}{dt}(C^i_j q^j) = C^i_j\dot{q}^j + \dot{C}^i_j q^j =  C^i_j\dot{q}^j  -\tilde{\Omega}^i_k C^k_j q^j =  C^i_j\dot{q}^j -\tilde{\Omega}^i_k \tilde{q}^k = \dot{\tilde{q}}^i \; \neq\; \tilde{v}^i 
$$

So, for the time-dependent rotating coordinates, $\tilde{q}^i$, the last equality in my equation (*) does NOT hold:

$$
 \tilde{v}^i(t)\tilde{\boldsymbol{\partial}}_i(t) = \pmb{v}_t = \tfrac{d}{dt} r_t \;\;\neq\;\; \tfrac{d}{dt}(\tilde{q}^i\circ {r})_t\tilde{\boldsymbol{\partial}}_i(t) = \dot{\tilde{q}}(t)\tilde{\boldsymbol{\partial}}_i(t)
$$
The same issue seems to arise whenever $\tilde{q}^i$ are coordinates relative to some moving frame or moving point.

**question:** It seems that, for coordinate functions which are not explicit functions of time,  $ \tfrac{d}{dt} r_t = \tfrac{d}{dt}(q^i\circ {r})_t\boldsymbol{\partial}_i$ is the proper formula for expressing velocity along a curve in a local coordinate basis. But this gives the wrong velocity if the coordinate functions are explicit functions of time. *What is the roper expression for the latter case?*  I'm not asking how to express the velocity in a rotating/moving frame in flat space; I know how to do that using basic newtonian mechanics. I want to do it using differential geometry. *I want a general formula for the velocity along a curve on any smooth manifold expressed in an explicitly time-dependent coordinate basis.*

---

Edit 1: Even if you don't wish to give the general answer, if you can simply resolve my example for rotating frames in flat space, that would also be apreciated.

Edit 2: If this is most easily addressed using the extended configuration space, $\mathcal{Q}\times\mathbb{R}$, feel free to do so.